# Как обнаружить устройство подключенное через USB (Мышь. клавиатура) на Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

Хочу сделать программку для изменения чувств. мыши на tkinter (или другой библиотеке), но не могу найти способ как найти подключенное устройство, в моем случае это мышка.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Если просто инфу о мыше, то:

```py
import usb.core

devices = usb.core.find(find_all=1)
for dev in devices:
    print (dev)
```

Если определить позицию, то:

```py
import pyautogui
pos = pyautogui.position()
print (pos)
```